# How do I create an Azure DevOps query that returns work items that have a successor?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am trying to create a query in Azure DevOps which filters work items based on properties of items that are linked to them, but I don't want to return the linked items.

I've tried using the 'work items and direct links' query type which gets me the results I need but also returns the successors as nested items. This doesn't work because I'm using the count of items in a dashboard as a numerical value and the widget also counts the nested/linked items in the count.

Full description of the query I want:

- Get all work items of any type
- Under a specific area path
- Whose state is not Done
- Which have one or more a related item(s) of any type
- Where the link type is 'Successor'
- Where the linked work item's State is not Removed

Is this something that is possible with ADO queries? I've been trying to a bit and can't find a way. The closest I've got is the 'Related Link Count' property my backlogs seem to have.

I tried using Work Items and Direct Links but this returns the links, which I do not want.

I tried filtering on Related Item Count but couldn't figure out how to check that the link type was specifically 'Successor' or that the related item was not Removed.